# Tkinter module on repl.it "no display name or $DISPLAY

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

this is my code which I am running on a Python 3 on Repl.it, unfortunately when I try and use the Tkinter module to create a window, it can't seem to find a display environment. Why is this and is there a fix for it?

```
    import tkinter
    window = tinter.Tk()
```

And the error is "_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable"
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You can't run tkinter in a web page.

Comment: Repl.it doesn't currently support tkinter but it supports a GUI library called REMI. You can see an example here: https://repl.it/@amasad/tictactoe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't believe you can configure this on repl.it, and if you could, I don't think it would be worth the hassle. Try running your program locally.

Let me try and answer this with an example.

The `$DISPLAY` environment variable is used to point to any X-server applications you have running on your PC. tkinter will look to your `$DISPLAY` variable to launch the X-server application (which in turn will launch the X11 protocol used for graphical interfaces).